# What machine learning algorithms can be used in this scenario?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, prediction

My data consists of objects as follows.

Obj1 - Color - shape - size - price - ranking

So I want to be able to predict what combination of color/shape/size/price is a good combination to get high ranking. Or even a combination could work like for eg: in order to get good ranking, the alg predicts best performance for this color and this shape. Something like that.

What are the advisable algorithms for such a prediction?

Also may be if you can briefly explain how I can approach towards the model building I would really appreciate it. Say for eg: my data looks like

```
Blue pentagon small $50.00 #5
Red  Squre    large $30.00 #3
```

So what is a useful prediction model that I should look at? What algorithm should I try to predict like say highest weightage is for price followed by color and then size. What if I wanted to predict in combinations like a Red small shape is less likely to higher rank compared to  pink small shape . (In essence trying to combine more than one nominal values column to make the prediction)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to learn models that you can interpret as a human. Depending on what type your ranking variable is, a number of different learners are possible.

If ranking is categorical (e.g. stars), a classifier is probably best. There are many in Weka. Some that produce models that are understandable by humans are the `J48` decision tree learner and the `OneR` rule learner.

If the ranking is continuous (e.g. a score), regression might be more appropriate. Suitable algorithms are for example `SimpleLogistic` and `LinearRegression`.

Alternatively, you could try clustering your examples with any of the algorithms in Weka and then analyzing the clusters. That is, ideally examples in a cluster would all be of the same (or very similar) ranking and you can have a look at the range of values of the other attributes and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your perspective. I have learned a little bit about J48 a little bit so I am definitely going to try it. I needed some advice on how I should modify my data. Now, my data is all nominal attributes. Like Yellow, Circle, Medium, $19.99, #458 (Rank).So how do you suggest, I try to model it. Or what should be the kind of output I should be looking at?

Comment: `J48` is able to work with only categorical data, so in principle there's no need to modify it. It would make sense to convert the price to a number though (simply delete the $ sign). Seeing the example ranking #458 suggests that classification is not the best approach though (no classes). I would suggest that you try regression instead. Depending on which algorithm you choose, you may need to convert your data to numbers (e.g. map small -> 0, medium -> 1, large -> 2 etc).

Comment: if I use 0 , 1 ,2 etc will the algorithms not use the literal value instead of just using them as different classes?

Comment: Yes. Some algorithms cannot handle categorical values though. If all you're interested in are the weights for the individual factors, this shouldn't matter though -- the most important factor will have the highest weight regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the combination as a linear equation, and apply a Monte Carlo algorithm (like **Genetic Algorithm**) to tune the parameters of the equation.

---

1. **Code** the color/shape/size/price/rankings into digital values.
2. Treat the combination as a **linear equation**, say `a*color + b*shape + c*size + d*price = ranking`.
3. Apply Genetic Algorithm to **tune a/b/c/d**, in order to make calculated `rankings` to be as closer to the ground-truth as possible.
4. Finally you got the equation, you could use it to:

   1) **find maximal rankings** by a simple linear planning;

   2) **predict rankings** by just assign other parameters.